# ubuntu 14.04 updating live usb to instal/updated nvidia driver and or login loop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, usb, graphics

So I have had so many problems trying to get this going.

- Hardware:
- CPU: xeon e5-2687w
- GPU: gtx 980 x2 sli   / nvidia n210 for testing purposes
- RAM: 32 gb gskill 1600 mhz
- MOBO: ASUS deluxe x79
- HD: samsung 1tb msata ssd with msata - sata3 adapter
  The set up is working fine with windows 10 so it is not the hardware unless incompatible with linux which I doubt.

Things I have done.
- Bios: Fast boot off and secure boot off

- swapped the 980's for the n210 to get to the installation media
- installed
- updated and downloaded latest nvidia driver (343.22)
- purge old NVIDIA files
- shutdown and swap the 980's back in
- receive login loop and switch to terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F1)
- stop lightdm service and install driver
- install fails with errors: Pre-Installation package failed proceed anyway? (I proceed) Failed to build Nvidia kernel module.
- switch to gdm and upon re-entry get no login screen what so ever and switch to terminal and receive about 3-5 seconds of display time before no video is displayed and no data taken from keyboard until I press (Ctrl +Alt +F1) every time to slowly reconfigure back to lightdm
- noticed in my log file (really don't remember what log) that nvidia was stopping due to: this server has a video driver ABI version of 19.0 that is not supported by this NVIDIA driver. Please check
  http://www.nvidia.com/ for driver updates or downgrade to an X
  server with a supported driver ABI.
- so now I switched back to the trusty n210 and my installation media to figure out that I am running off of nouveau.
- how could I update the live version so I would be able to just install and have the correct driver ready to go?

Answer (score 0):

So I went a head and just started taking step by step notes of my situation and these are my notes in case any happens to stumble across this in the future.

hardware:
CPU: xeon e5-2687w
GPU: gtx 980 x2 in sli (n210 for testing legacy)
RAM: 32 gigs of G.Skill
MOBO: asus deluxe x79
PSU: evga 1200 w p2 supernova

**1** install ubuntu with n210

**2** whilst using n210 update and upgrade restart

**3** after restart check additional drivers and make nvidia proprietary driver default

**** Note **** every chance before step 3 I swap the n210 for the 980 sli and back and step 4 is
the first that the 980 sli works.

**4** this is where the login loop starts.

**5** I try guest account and it does the same determining that is not an user account issue and
rather a driver issue (nvidia driver version 340.23)

**6** I set .Xauthority to .Xauthority.back to generate a new one and restarted lightdm service 
and login loop still persists

**7** reading lightdm logs

```
lightdm.log:
        DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display on VT 7
        DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-1.log
        DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:1
        DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Launching X Server
        DEBUG: Launching process 3385: /user/bin/X -core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
        DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
        DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.Accounts
        DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
        DEBUG: Loading users from ofg.freedesktop.Accounts
        DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
x-0-greeter.log:
        DEBUG: Generating properties error for: 26
        DEBUG: Error getting properties on a new menuitem: Error getting properties for ID
        DEBUG: Generating properties error for: 18
        DEBUG: Error getting properties on a new menuitem: Error getting properties for ID
        DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/Forever_by_Shady_S.jpg complete
        DEBUG: User/org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
        DEBUG: user-list.vala:1030: Adding/updating user trevor (trevor)
        DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:209: Screensaver activated
        DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:211: Screensaver disabled
        DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:209: Screensaver activated
x-0.log:
        xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3.1~trusty1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
        Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
            Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
            to make sure that you ve the latest version.
        Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
            (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
            (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown,
        (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Oct  8 20:06:11 2015
        (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
        mobprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_340': No such device
x-1.log:
            Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
            to make sure that you ve the latest version.
        Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
            (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
            (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown,
        (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Oct  8 19:45:47 2015
        (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
        mobprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_340': No such device
        Failed to switch from vt07 to vt01: Input/output error
        Failed to switch from vt07 to vt01: Input/output error
```

**8** figured out that the gtx980 and 970 do not work under the proprietary nvidia driver and cuda.

******NOTE****** linux kernel has to work with nvidia kernel and cuda has to work as well

**9** reinstall ubuntu

**10** update upgrade and restart. 980 still does not work switching back to n210

**11** Install modprobe package from: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/nvidia-modprobe
 (which I dont think was necessary since I think step 12 comes with it)

**12** download latest cuda package from: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx

**13** enter cli and "sudo service lightdm stop" to kill xorg

**14** install the latest cuda package

**15** at the end I get: 
    A system reboot is required to continue installation. please reboot then run the 
    installer again. an attempt has been made to disable nouveau. if this message persists 
    after reboot, please see the display driver log file at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log 
    for more information.
**16** shuting down and replacing the n210 with the 980's

**17** installed both 980's and logged in now time to check the environment

**18** about this computer states: Graphics Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)

**19** checking additional updates: 
    nvidia proprietary drivers have been updated to the 346.96
    and the system is currently using xorg xserver nouveau

**20** running installer again as the installer instructed

**21** killing x environment

**22** the installer failed on the driver portion due to: 
    The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure that 
    the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly.
    If you know that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly, 
    you may pass the location of the kernel source with the '--kernel-source-path' flag.

**23** going to restart lightdm and try to find out if the kernel sources are there. (presumably yes)
and if so I will manually switch to the nvidia driver

**24** couldn't find what I was looking for and getting impatient, going for the manual nvidia switch

**25** worked! time to update upgrade

Sources:
1:http //blender.stackexchange com/questions/19336/how-to-enable-cuda-on-ubunutu-14-04-for-a-gtx-970
2:https //developer.nvidia com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx
3:http //blenderartists org/forum/showthread.php?355600-GPU-rendering-with-gtx-970-on-ubuntu
4:http //packages.ubuntu com/trusty-backports/nvidia-modprobe

hope this helps someone.